# JOIN the same variable twice in one SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, sql

First, I have oversimplified my tables just to drive the point of the question home. I have two tables where the first is "Clubs" and the second "Fixtures"

The club database has a club_ID and club_Name
The fixtures has the Fixt_Date and then the ID numbers of the home and away teams.

How do I display a query that shows the date and then the names of both clubs?

```
SELECT Fixtures.Match_Date AS Date, Clubs.Club_Name AS Home, Clubs.Club_Name AS AWAY
FROM Fixtures INNER JOIN Clubs ON Fixtures.Away = Clubs.ID AND Fixtures.Home = Clubs.ID;
```

I have a feeling this is horribly wrong, but I have zero to none experience with SQL yet.

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Try using `IN` operator..

```
SELECT F.Match_Date AS Date, 
       Max(case when C.ID = F.Home then C.Club_Name end) AS Home, 
       Max(case when C.ID = F.Away then C.Club_Name end) AS AWAY
   FROM Fixtures F 
   INNER JOIN Clubs C ON C.ID in (F.Away, F.Home);
   Group by F.Match_Date
```

your query will work only when both `Away` and `Home` contains same Club `Id`

Comment: I think you havent understood the question. The OP is trying to show the home's and away's club names instead of their ids.

Comment: @FabianBigler - Yep.. totally misunderstood the question... Hope it makes little sense now..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT Fixtures.Match_Date AS Date,    
       hc.Club_Name AS Home,  
       ac.Club_Name AS AWAY    
FROM   Fixtures 
INNER JOIN 
       Clubs ac 
    ON Fixtures.Away = ac.ID 
INNER JOIN
       Clubs hc   
    ON Fixtures.Home = hc.ID;
```

Comment: This is the correct answer: use aliases so that the same table can be joined twice.

Comment: This seems to work. As I oversimplified the question, the total query still needs some work, but this brings me a long way!

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is getting the club's names instead of ID's, you can also use subselects:

SELECT Match_Date AS Date, (SELECT Club_Name FROM Clubs WHERE ID = Home) AS Home, (SELECT Club_Name FROM Clubs WHERE ID = Away) AS Away FROM Fixtures

Note: With this solution, the clubs_id must be the PK.